# Datepicker change format notworking

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I have this in a javascript file:

```
$('#edit-date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',      
});
```

When I initially select the edit field, nothing happens. I get an error saying "datepicker is not a function". But afterwards, when I chose a date, it works!

Datepicker format not working at the first time :

[image]

When I submit, its working:

[image]

Comment: What is the context of the javascript code you provided? When is it called? Can you show more code?

Comment: Amazing handwriting!!

Comment: I have plugged your code into [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0tj4djx/) and it works for me.

Comment: ok, the problem was from the core of drupal, i have enabled UI Jquery , its work now, thanks for all :)